# Make this dropdown menu to work on "touch" surface pro IE 11

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, touch

I found these codes which produce the dropdown menu that is close to what we need. However, it does not work with touch device. At least it doesn't work on my surface pro IE 11. As your finger move off the menu, the dropdown menu disappear before you can select any menu item. How do I make it to work on touch?
http://fiddle.jshell.net/r6ty9nw9/3/

```
<nav>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul id="menu" class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Categories</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="purple"><a href="#">Design</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">InDesign</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="green"><a href="#">Writing</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Copywriting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Journalism</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Poetry</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Storytelling</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Copywriting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Journalism</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Poetry</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Storytelling</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="aqua"><a href="#">Accounting</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Taxes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Credit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Asset Management</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="red"><a href="#">Marketing</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Print</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Digital</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Presenting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="blue"><a href="#">Development</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HTML5/CSS3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ruby on Rails</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="gold"><a href="#">Photography</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Mechanics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Composition</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>

$(function(){
    var defaultMenuHeight = 0;
    $('a[href="#"]').on('click', function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });

    $('#menu > li').on('mouseover', function(e){
                        var menuItem = $(this);
                        menuItem.find('> a').mouseover(function(e){
                            $(this).next().css({"padding-bottom":0});
              defaultMenuHeight = menuItem.find('ul').actual('outerHeight');
           });
        $(this).find("ul:first").show();
        $(this).find('> a').addClass('active');
        //HERE FIX
        if(defaultMenuHeight == 0){
            defaultMenuHeight = menuItem.find('ul').actual('outerHeight');
        }
    }).on('mouseout', function(e){
          $(this).find("ul:first").hide();
          $(this).find('> a').removeClass('active');
       });

    $('#menu li li').on('mouseover',function(e){
        if($(this).has('ul').length) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('expanded');
            var ttlLiHeight = 0;
            $(this).find('ul li').each(function() {
                var curLiHeight = $(this).actual('innerHeight');
                ttlLiHeight += curLiHeight;
            });
            if(ttlLiHeight >= defaultMenuHeight){
                var difference = ttlLiHeight-defaultMenuHeight;
                $(this).parent('#menu li ul').css({"padding-bottom":difference});
            }else{
                $(this).parent('#menu li ul').css({"padding-bottom":0});
            }
            $('#result').html("Default Height: " + defaultMenuHeight + "<br>padding bottom: " + difference);
        }
        $('ul:first',this).parent().find('> a').addClass('active');
        $('ul:first',this).show();
    }).on('mouseout',function(e){
         $(this).parent().removeClass('expanded');
         $('ul:first',this).parent().find('> a').removeClass('active');
         $('ul:first', this).hide();
      });
});
```

Comment: I tried the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/r6ty9nw9/3/) on an iPhone 6 and the menu does not disappear when your finger moves off of it. The thing that you might want to add is the ability to close the menu by touching outside of it.

Comment: Hmm..you're right. I tried it on iPhone 6 and it seemed to work. It doesn't work on my surface pro (IE 11), however.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `touchstart` event and `touchend` event in your event list to support touchable devices.

```
$('#menu > li').on('mouseover touchstart touchend', function(e){});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/alireza_safian/r6ty9nw9/4/)

Comment: As a commenter above mentioned about iphone 6, I tried your method and it still didn't work on my surface pro IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

Use "ontouchstart"

```
<a href="" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('classname')">Menu</a>
```

This will toggle classname during touch event and you can show/hide your dropdown

Comment: No dropdown menu. Only flipping tiles, mate.

Comment: You can make dropdown using same method. For that project i use flipper. ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('classname')" can used to add class in touch start and toggle class